# Forecasting future raster values of a Starma model

Tags: r, time-series, r-raster, forecast

I am using R package starma to develop a space-time autoregressive moving average model of a raster data. I am having trouble getting to forecast future values for the region whose data is being modelled. I have tried to use the predict() function which seems not to accomodate starma object. Any assistance or directions will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO, please spend some time to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), to help the community to help you. Also, it is a good idea to explain what you have tried and done so far and provide an example of the desired output

Comment: Can starma data make predictions to new data? That is not necessarily the case. If it can, then please show how with a simple example (a small data.frame). From there we can go to the raster data.